# Creating a swap contract using solidity

Tags: solidity

Consider Three Erc20 Tokens : A, B and C

Say A and B are public tokens already deployed by someone else in the world and C is a new token that i am building myself.

Now, i want to create a swap contract say SwC.

What it aims to achieve is this :-

If an user U1 wants to swap x amount of (A and B) into x amount of C, the contract should send a approve request to U1's wallet (take meta mask for example) asking to approve a transaction for sending x amount of A and x amount of B from U1's wallet to our swap contract itself (i.e. SwC).

If the transaction is approved and mined successfully, then SwC should send x amount of C to U1's addy.

How can this be achieved ?
(Do note that i am trying to make user transfer 2 different tokens in one transaction to our Swc in order to recieve one single token C).

Comment: You don't want to call `approve` from solidity since it will be interpreted as coming the your contract. Instead you have to call it from the UI, so it will be sent by the user.

Comment: OK. Thx for suggestion. I have pretty much figured out the solution. I have done same as you have said in your comment.